# Deseralize an object that contain dynamic properties JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

how to deserialize this?
PS: dynamic1,dynamic2 ,etc.. each one has totally different name

JSON:

```
"bob": {
    "dynamic1": 1,
    "dynamic2": 5,
    "dynamic3": 9,
},

 public class Bob
 {     
        [JsonProperty("bob")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
 }

public class Root
{

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public Dictionary<Bob, int> DataItems { get; set; }
}
var resultJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Bob` does not correctly represent the data you have in your JSON. Your json shows `Bob` to be an object in your class, your `Jsonproperty` defines `bob` as a string.

For your JSON:

```
{
  "bob": {
    "dynamic1": 1,
    "dynamic2": 5,
    "dynamic3": 9,
  }
}
```

you should use the `RootObject` Class the following way to properly deserialize your JSON,

```
public class RootObject {
    [JsonProperty("bob")]
    public Dictionary<string, int> Bob { get; set; }
}

// and in your main, use the following to deserialize
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

In the above example, obj has a Dictionary containing `dynamic1`, `dynamic2` and `dynamic3` as Keys and 1, 5, and 9 as the respective values.

PS: When you deserialize the json into your class, the `JsonProperty` **must** exactly match the property in the JSON itself. If you use `[JsonProperty("Bob")]` with capital B and you have lowercase in json, it wont work. JSON is case sensetive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic):

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
int dynamic1 = obj.dynamic1;
```